# Do we really need the airspace classes tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[image]

I *think* they were created recently, and they are rarely (sometimes not) used, compared to the main 'airspace' tag.

My thinking is, for example, if I tag a question with Class-C, Class-C is not the same everywhere. So what is the usefulness when a user decides to filter/search by `[class-c-airspace]`?

What are your thoughts?

Should they (apart from SUA?) become synonyms of [airspace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much point in them myself, but after thinking some more I can at least think of a couple of use cases for the class-specific tags:

- A student researching a specific airspace type
- A pilot with little class B experience looking for more information

But the general [airspace-classes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace-classes) tag seems to me to have little or no value. What's the practical difference between it and [airspace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace)?

I'd remove the [airspace-classes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace-classes) tag but leave the class-specific ones for now, until we can see if people are really using them or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need them.

Unless we get a high number of questions about airspace, it is better to merge all airspace questions into one tag.

Furthermore we will run into the ICAO / FAA / [whatever jurisdiction] problem once we head that direction.